# Django Jinja include static file with path in variable

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I need to do something like this:
`{% load static %} {% include {% static path %} %}`

I have a lot of files, and I give this path variable in context, and it also contains in static directory, so I cant just do
`{% include path %}`

Also I found that I cant just put function inside another function: {% %} inside {% %}
I looked at the Jinja's documention to find how to deal with this inside functions, but that didnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you treat it with some custom filters or custom tags.
But I guess this would work for your case.

```
{% load static %}
{% with static_path=static path %}
  {% include static_path %}
{% endwith %}
```

---

```
from django import template
from django.templatetags.static import static

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def include_static(path):
    return static(path)
```

And then

```
{% load custom_filters %}

{% with static_path=path|include_static %}
  {% include static_path %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just moved all files to templates. Idk why I wanted to store it all in static